# How to use LWUIT theme

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I want to use LWUIT for making GUI of my application in good way. But the problem I am facing is I am not able to use a theme.

I had followed this link [The Lightweight User Interface Toolkit LWUIT An Introduction](http://www.java2s.com/Article/Java/J2ME-Wireless/The_Lightweight_User_Interface_Toolkit_LWUIT_An_Introduction.htm).

I had used this code to load the theme. But it is giving me exception.

```
try {
Resources r = Resources.open("theme.res");
UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("theme"));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
System.out.println("Couldn't load theme.");
}
```

Comment: can you please post exception stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you are stored ResourceEdit file? I think you made the mistake here. Check with your workspace.

Store the ResourceEdit file inside "src" folder.

`Display.init(this)` method must be called before any Form is shown. See this [link](http://today.java.net/article/2008/09/19/using-styles-themes-and-painters-lwuit) for your reference.

Comment: I had stored my resource file in src folder and did the same as shown in the link.But then also it is showing same problem

Comment: Are u getting any exception? did u create the theme inside of resourceEdit? check with ur resourceEdit again.

Answer (score 1):

from the code it seems it could throw `FileNotFoundException`

Double check your `theme.res` file should be in default package. if its in some package then

```
Resources r = Resources.open("/com/mycompany/somepackage/theme.res");
```